# Creating a new column in a data frame based on row values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to get the following result without using a for loop or df.apply()

The result for each row should be the row values up until the group index.

```
   group  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0      2  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
1      5  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
2      7  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h

   group                    result
0      2                 [a, b, c]
1      5        [s, t, u, v, w, x]
2      7  [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

Comment: Hi! You forgot to ask a precise question!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), filter `group` column and variable column in [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and last aggregate `list`:

```
s = (df.melt('group', ignore_index=False)
       .astype({'variable':int})
       .query("group >= variable")
       .groupby(level=0)['value']
       .agg(list))

df = df[['group']].join(s.rename('result'))
print (df)
   group                    result
0      2                 [a, b, c]
1      5        [s, t, u, v, w, x]
2      7  [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

Or use `apply`:

```
df = (df.set_index('group')
        .rename(columns=int)
        .apply(lambda x: list(x[x.index <= x.name]), axis=1)
        .reset_index(name='result'))
print (df)
   group                    result
0      2                 [a, b, c]
1      5        [s, t, u, v, w, x]
2      7  [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know which method would be faster on a massive data frame (say 1000 x 1000)?

Comment: @Nikolas - Try both solution, not idea exactly. Only guessing - first one.